# How to improve the quality of images in movie saved via videowriter in matlab?

Tags: matlab-figure

I am making a movie in MATLAB with 3 subplot. When I am saving a figure as png it looks great but saving in video mode looks ugly. How to improve the images of video. Specially to remove extra white space regions. Also is there any possibility to see 360 rotation in elevation angle. I am using Linux machine.

Here is the image in png 
[image: two muppets]
Same image saved in video mode 
[image: two muppets]
MATLAB Code

```
 v = VideoWriter('myFile.avi');
 v.FrameRate = 1;
 open(v);

 h1=figure;
 set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [15 5]);
 set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 15 5]);

 d=linspace(0,360,15); % azimuth angle 
 first=length(d);
 for j=1:first
      viewScene(j,:)=[-d(j),1];
 end

 d=linspace(-90,90,10); % elevation angle 
 for j=1:length(d)
        viewScene(j+first,:)=[-38,d(j)];
 end
 final=first+length(d);

 for t=1:final
     for i=1:3 
         subplot(1,3,i)
         plot3()
         hold on 
         plot3()
         axis vis3d;
         view(viewScene(t,:))
         set(findobj(gcf,'type','axes'),'visible','off');
     end
     frame=getframe(gcf);
     writeVideo(v,frame)
     hold off 
  end
  close(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, VideoWriter creates a Motion JPEG-AVI file. You can modify the Quality parameter to get better quality images. `Quality = 100` gives the best results.

Another option is to write Uncompressed AVI's which will write the data as is without any corruption but can result in larger files. You can also try and convert your image into an indexed image using RGB2IND function and write an Indexed AVI which is also lossless and will give roughly 1/3rd the size of Uncompressed AVIs.

You can also give MPEG-4  a shot.

The thing is that MJPEG and MPEG-4, they are used for compressing natural scenic images where high-frequency information i.e. edges and transitions is lost. Your image is not a natural scenery and hence this is expected.